# I am trying to hide and show react native date picker after clicking touchable opacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native application and I am trying to figure out how to hide the datepicker after clicking a touchable opacity component.

**Here is the logic for setting up the datetimepicker**

```
 const [showCompleted, setShowCompleted] = useState(false);
 const [isHidden, setHidden] = useState(true);

 const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
   const completedDate = selectedDate || Date;
   setShowCompleted(Platform.OS === 'ios');
   setCompletedDate(completedDate);
 };

 const showDatepicker = () => {
   if (isHidden === true) {
     setHidden({ isHidden: false });
     setShowCompleted(true);
   } else {
     setHidden({ isHidden: true });
   }
 };
```

**Here is the logic for the UI**

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      height: 50,
      margin: 15,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderRadius: 5
    }}
    onPress={showDatepicker}
  >
    <View flexDirection='row'>
      <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 15, margin: 15 }}>
        Completed Date
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 15, fontSize: 14, marginLeft: 140 }}>
        Mar 17, 2020
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  {isHidden ? (
    <View>
      {showCompleted && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID='dateTimePicker'
          placeholder='Completed Date'
          value={completedDate}
          mode='date'
          display='default'
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  ) : null}
```

Any thoughts welcome. I am trying to accomplish the same effect as scheduling a new event on an iphone. Where you touch the date and the datepicker comes down and you touch it again and it goes up. Currently, it goes down but I can't figure out how to get it to go back. I think I am overlooking something very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems like you're updating the state in the wrong way, you are saving object with containing data, instead of doing that, try to just put the `Boolean` value instead, so simplify your opener function like this

```
const showDatepicker = () => {
   setShowCompleted(!showCompleted);
};
```

So each time your function gets executed `setShowCompleted` will negate the boolean value of `showCompleted`, so if you first get `false` when you click on the button the `false` becomes to `true` and next time `true` becomes `false` and so on.

So you can remove `isHidden` state and just use `showCompleted` value instead